# Firestore says I have inequality filter on multiple properties, when I don't

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a "small hack" to avoid reading the User document everytime the page loads. So I save it locally, everytime the page loads I get the local version, get the `updated_at` property and then do something like `WHERE last_updated > {{updated_at}}`. For that, I want to use this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('User')
.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
.where('updated_at', '>', updated_at)
.get()
```

As you can see, I have one equality (`==`) and one inequality (`>`). Why do I get the following error on the console:

```
FirebaseError: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties: updated_at
    at new t (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:47054)
    at t.fromRpcStatus (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:116660)
    at t.fromWatchChange (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:125914)
    at t.onMessage (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:242411)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:241212
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:241997
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js:1:144869
```

I am doing this to try to avoid reading from the database if the local version is the same as the one in the database. Maybe if you have a better way, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: *firebaser here* I just reproduced this behavior in https://jsbin.com/zexapuv/edit?js,console and am asking around why these filters would trigger that error. The only thing I can think of is that `documentId()` is somehow special, but in that case I'd expect a more explicit error message about that field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The equality check you have on `documentId()` is internally converted into a range check by Firestore, because the keys are stored as the last items in existing indexes (if I understand correctly). And that means that server-side you're trying to perform two inequality/range checks, which isn't allowed.

So the behavior you are seeing is correct. But it's definitely not intuitive, and the error message is also not helpful. We'll look for a way to improve the error message by detecting this combination.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I implemented the following hack: I added the id as part of the field name on which I made the check for the latest version. If your logic allows you to do that, for you this would mean:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('User')
.where(id + '_updated_at', '>', updated_at)
.get()
```

This allows to bundle in just one `where` statement both the check on the id and on the date (documents with different ids wont have the field `id + '_updated_at'` and wont therefore be selected).

Worked like a charm for me